# How to display code output in current gvim window?

Tags: vim

I'm (slowly) teaching myself how to program, and I'm using gVim as my text editor. So, I have a question, that I was wondering if gVim has this feature. So, lets say I am writing Hello World in Java.

I can write the program in vim, hit esc, then type (using my pattern matching skills):

```
:!javac %
```

(this will open up a vimrun window, compile the code and list any errors)

then:

```
:!java hello (or whatever the class is named)
```

Then a new window pops up and displays the output of the code. So what I want to do is display any compilation errors, then the output, **in the current vim window**, without opening a new window. So I would like, if possible, to display the code (for lack of knowledge of the correct term) among the blue squiggles. After extensive googling, the closest I could find to what I want is

```
:read !java hello
```

and that will paste the output below the code. But this is not *quite* what I want. So is it possible to display any compilation errors, and code output, specifically where I'd like it?

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is to use [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) (Java build tool, Java's equivalent of `make`). From [here](http://blog.vinceliu.com/2007/08/vim-tips-for-java-1-build-java-files.html):

> Add the following lines in your .vimrc:
>
> ```
> autocmd BufRead *.java set efm=%A\ %#[javac]\ %f:%l:\ %m,%-Z\ %#[javac]\ %p^,%-C%.%#
> autocmd BufRead set makeprg=ant\ -find\ build.xml
> ```

Then make a `build.xml` file for your project, and you can then do `:make` (or `:make run`, or any other target) to run Ant on the appropriate target. How to build the `build.xml` is a bit outside the scope of the question, but you can follow the [Ant Hello World tutorial](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html), which should be enough to get you started.

The `:make` command will execute the make tool (in this case, Ant), and put the output into a special window in Vim. In case of compiler output, you might also be able to press Enter on a line to jump to the appropriate line of code. (Not sure, I don't remember doing it with Java).

Another way to go about this is to use the [ConqueShell](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Conque-Shell) plugin, which allows you to run and interact with terminal programs in a Vim window.